# Advanced resources exclusion rules from a WAR usng Maven

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

My server side technology is defining pages using two files located in the same directory, with the same name but different extensions: one with the .html extension, the other with .xsp. Out of these files, a compile time builder generates a java .class that will be loaded and executed by the server.
In the final war, I'd like to exclude both the .html and .xsp files, as they are not needed.

The question is: how can I only exclude the .html that have an associated .xsp, while keep including the ones without an associated .xsp? Resources filter currently use file name patterns, but this is not sufficient in my case. Is there a way to write a custom filter that will check for the existence of the .xsp and then instruct the war plugin to include the .html or not?

Comment: create your own plugin, perhaps extending resources plugin? Invoke script with exec plugin?

Comment: i would ask google about that and look for `xsp maven plugin` which worth to do...

Answer (score 0):

I finally successfully experimented two solutions:

1. Extending the maven-war plugin
2. Post-processing the WAR file

I looked at the maven-war-plugin source code, but it is almost impossible to extend as some of the interesting methods (ex: gathering the list of tasks) are private. As a result, I had to clone the whole project and injected my code in. That worked but this is not satisfactory, as I don't want to maintain it over time when the original plugin evolves.

Post processing was actually a lot easier. I created another plugin that executes in the package phase, right after the war generation. This plugin simply create a new temporary war, by copying the content of the original one, minus the undesired files. Finally, it replaces the original war by the temp one. That sounds a lot safer in the longer term.